# Collect the coefficients through the Cos argument

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, arguments

I have for example the following expression:

`Cos[a + b] + 2 Cos[2 a + b] + 2 Cos[a + 2 b] + 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b] +  Cos[a + b + c] + 2 Cos[2 a + b + c] + 2 Cos[a + 2 b + c] +  4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + c] + Cos[a + b + 2 c] + 2 Cos[2 a + b + 2 c] +  2 Cos[a + 2 b + 2 c] + 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + 2 c`

I need to collect the coefficients associated with a specific argument from the cosines.
For example, collect all the coefficients that the Cos argument its the form of **Cos[ka+jb+2c]** where k,j are Real numbers. So for this example the answer would be something like **{Cos[a+b+2c], 2Cos[2a+b+2c],  2 Cos[a + 2 b + 2 c],  4 Cos[2a + 2 b + 2 c]}**

I have no ideia on how to do that, thanks for the help.

Edit:
I thought the Cases command had solved it but I can't understand why the command fails in the following expression

`expre=625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5a-b-4c-4d]-9/256 cosI e^4 Cos[3a+b-4c-4d]-  9/16 cosI e^2 Cos[3a+b-2c-4d]`

`cosI, e` are real numbers

`Cases[expre, coeff_.  Cos[_ + 5 a]]` gives `{625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d]}`

but

`Cases[expre, coeff_.  Cos[_  -4 d]]` gives `{}`

`Cases[expre, coeff_.  Cos[_  -4c]]` also gives `{}`

Comment: I just saw your update. See my answer for how to adjust.

Comment: Hi, if you write a comment below an answer, the person that wrote it can get notified. You can get an answer quicker like that than if you only edit your question (which you should still do in order to get an answer from other members). The person that answered might not know that the question was edited as far as I understand.

Comment: If you would like to use the full expression in the argument of Cos when using the listcos function in my answer see the section [Edit2: ...] between [ ]:

Comment: I modified the section bellow the line ------------ that explains why `Cases[expre, coeff_.  Cos[_  -4 d]]` so that it is more clear and detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

`Cases[expre, coeff_. Cos[_ -4 d]]` did not work because of the evaluation order in Mathematica and the parity of Cos. To block the parity of Cos a quick way is to insert a function in its argument like Cos[x]->Cos[t[x]] where t is an undefined function then use Cases, then remove the function t. This is done in the code below:

[ **Edit2:**

If you would like to use the full expression in the argument of Cos when using the listcos function below like:

**Input:**

```
expre // listcos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d]
```

**Desired output:**

```
{625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d]}
```

then `Cases[expression,_.Cos[symbol+_]]` (in the listcos definition it is `Cos[t[symbol+_]]`) will not work because _ expects another expression. In that case it suffices to replace +_ with +_. as follows:

**code version 2 :**

```
Clear[listcos]; 
    listcos[symbol_][expression_] := 
     Module[{t, s}, 
      Cases[expression /. Cos[s_] -> Cos[t[s]], _. Cos[t[symbol + _.]]] /. 
       t -> Identity]
```

For more information on _. see Default and OneIdentity in the documentation

]

**(previous or version 1) code:**

```
Clear[listcos]; 
listcos[symbol_][expression_] := 
 Module[{t, s}, 
  Cases[expression /. Cos[s_] -> Cos[t[s]], _. Cos[t[symbol + _]]] /. 
   t -> Identity]
```

Now you can use the function listcos like:

**Input :**

```
expre // listcos[3*a]
```

**Output :**

```
{-(9/256) cosI e^4 Cos[3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/16) cosI e^2 Cos[
   3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d]}
```

**Input :**

```
expre // listcos[-4*d]
```

**Output :**

```
{625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/256) cosI e^4 Cos[
   3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/16) cosI e^2 Cos[3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d]}
```

**Input :**

```
expre // listcos[3*a + b]
```

**Output:**

```
{-(9/256) cosI e^4 Cos[3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/16) cosI e^2 Cos[
   3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d]}
```

---

**Edit:**

**Explanation concerning why** `Cases[expre, coeff_. Cos[_ -4 d]]` **did not work**

`Cases[expre, coeff_. Cos[_ -4 d]]` is not working because of the evaluation order in mathematica and simplifications due to the parity of Cos.

For example consider the following list:

**Input:**

```
{Cos[a - c], Cos[b - c], Cos[d - c], Cos[z - c], Cos[_ - c], 
 Cos[5*aa - c], Cos[sr - c]}
```

**Output:**

```
{Cos[a - c], Cos[b - c], Cos[c - d], Cos[c - z], Cos[c - _], 
 Cos[5 aa - c], Cos[c - sr]}
```

Some arguments are flipped using the parity of Cos. How to predict which ones ?

**Experiment:**

```
Sort[{a, d, c, b, z, 5*aa, _, lr, sr}]
```

output : `{a, 5 aa, b, c, d, lr, sr, z, _}`

The arguments that are flipped are the ones that were of the form expression-c with expression>c according to Sort. That is Cos[expression1-expression2] is evaluated as Cos[expression2-expression1] if expression1>expression according to Sort.

This expression and sign flip caused `Cos[_-4d]` to be understood as `Cos[4d-_]` which was not in the original expression.

You can use that explanation to understand the output from the following input:

```
{Cases[Cos[4*d - u] + g, Cos[4*d - _]], 
 Cases[Cos[4*d - u] + g, Cos[_ - 4*d]], 
 Cases[Cos[u - 4*d] + g, Cos[_ - 4*d]], 
 Cases[Cos[b - 4*d] + g, Cos[_ - 4*d]]}
```

Answer (score 6):

One way, assuming `expr` is a linear combination of cosines:

```
expr = Cos[a + b] + 2 Cos[2 a + b] + 2 Cos[a + 2 b] + 
   4 Cos[2 a + 2 b] + Cos[a + b + c] + 2 Cos[2 a + b + c] + 
   2 Cos[a + 2 b + c] + 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + c] + Cos[a + b + 2 c] + 
   2 Cos[2 a + b + 2 c] + 2 Cos[a + 2 b + 2 c] + 
   4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + 2 c];

Cases[expr, HoldPattern[coeff_. Cos[_ + 2 c]]]
(*
{Cos[a + b + 2 c], 2 Cos[2 a + b + 2 c], 2 Cos[a + 2 b + 2 c], 
 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + 2 c]}
*)
```

New example:

```
Cases[expre, HoldPattern[coeff_. Cos[_ + (-4) d]]]
(*
{625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d],
 -(9/256) cosI e^4 Cos[3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d],
 -(9/16) cosI e^2 Cos[3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d]}
*)

(* Alternative *)
Cases[expre, coeff_. Cos[_ + HoldPattern[-4 d]]]
```

But not

```
Cases[expre, HoldPattern[coeff_. Cos[_ -4 d]]]
```

As always, examine the full forms of pattern and potential matches to debug pattern-matching problems:

```
Cos[3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d] // FullForm
coeff_. Cos[_ - 4 d] // FullForm
HoldPattern[coeff_. Cos[_ - 4 d]] // FullForm
(* output omitted; pay attn to how -4 d is parsed *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two test cases:

```
expr = Cos[a + b] + 2 Cos[2 a + b] + 2 Cos[a + 2 b] + 
  4 Cos[2 a + 2 b] + Cos[a + b + c] + 2 Cos[2 a + b + c] + 
  2 Cos[a + 2 b + c] + 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + c] + Cos[a + b + 2 c] + 
  2 Cos[2 a + b + 2 c] + 2 Cos[a + 2 b + 2 c] + 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + 2 c]
expr2 =
  625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d] - 
   9/256 cosI e^4 Cos[3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d] - 
   9/16 cosI e^2 Cos[3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d]
```

This separates the sum into a list, then extracts the angles inside the `Cos[]`, turns that angel it to a list, and checks that list for `2c`:

```
Select[List @@ expr, 
 MemberQ[List @@ # & /@ Cases[#, coeff_. Cos[angle_] -> angle], 
   2 c, {2}] &]
(*{2 Cos[2 a + b + 2 c], 2 Cos[a + 2 b + 2 c], 4 Cos[2 a + 2 b + 2 c]}*)
```

This checks the second test case for `-4c`:

```
Select[List @@ expr2, 
 MemberQ[List @@ # & /@ 
    Cases[#, coeff_. Cos[angle_] -> angle], -4 c, {2}] &]
(*{625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/256) cosI e^4 Cos[3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d]}*)
```

and `-4d`

```
Select[List @@ expr2, 
 MemberQ[List @@ # & /@ 
    Cases[#, coeff_. Cos[angle_] -> angle], -4 d, {2}] &]
(*{625/768 cosI e^4 Cos[5 a - b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/256) cosI e^4 Cos[
   3 a + b - 4 c - 4 d], -(9/16) cosI e^2 Cos[3 a + b - 2 c - 4 d]}*)
```

Comment: I was inspired by the use of Select here and I wrote a code that is a bit similar in spirit that uses `FreeQ` to not have to worry about the level in the expression: `Select[Cases[expre, _. Cos[_]] /. Cos[h_] :> Cos[\[FormalF] /@ h],    Not[FreeQ[#, \[FormalF][-4*d]]] &] /. \[FormalF] -> Identity`. If OP is 100 percent sure that the arguments in Cos only appear in Cos and that this will never change in the notebook then a simpler version is `Select[Cases[expre, _. Cos[_]], Not[FreeQ[#, -4*d]] &]`