# Global order setting

Tags: output-formatting, variable-definitions

I'm working on mathematical models using many alphabets and Greek characters as parameters or variables. However, The outputs show them in undesired order. Here are some examples:

`(1/2)*(\[Beta]^2*(-A + m*\[Delta] + \[CapitalDelta])^2*\[Theta]1 + k*(m^2*\[Beta]^2 - 8*\[Beta]*\[Theta]1 + 2*m*\[Beta]*\[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]1^2))`
[image]

this $(-A+m \delta+\Delta)^2$ should have been written like this $(A - m\delta - \Delta)^2$

or this $1/2 (-m \beta + \lambda1)$ should be like $1/2 (\lambda1-m \beta)$

How can I get the entire notebook's output in the desired order?

Comment: Edit your question to include the Mathematica code (InputForm) for your expressions so that they can be copy and pasted into a notebook

Comment: `expr /. (z_)^2 :> (-z)^2`

Comment: To make a simpler example, the input `b-a` returns `-a+b`. That is because `Plus` has attribute [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) and uses a certain built-in ordering. I would not try to change that. It is not important and not worth it. Just accept the built-in ordering when you do calculations. If you have to include a result in a paper, you can change it then if you can't help it.

Comment: Just to add on the comment above `b-a` returns `-a+b` and `a - b` returns `a-b` because Mathematica is imposing a canonical order which might make it easier to match patterns and possibly also simplify. The order of `a` and `b` in the expression is the same as `Sort[{b,a}]`. This automatic sorting can also make pattern matching a bit more difficult when the pattern is inside an even function such as `Cos`. An example of that is given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272242/86543)

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of terms in expressions is not aesthetic but functional. Terms are reordered as part of expression canonicalization. This cannot be changed.

You can change how expressions are displayed (not stored) to some extent. Applying [`TraditionalForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) produces an output with a more pleasing order, usually avoiding leading minus signs.

You can change the default format type for a notebook. In the Option Inspector, choose to change settings for the current notebook, then search for CommonDefaultFormatTypes and change "Output" to TraditionalForm. Doing this may not always be productive as TraditionalForm is not always unambiguous.  I would suggest applying TraditionalForm manually to selected outputs.  Command-Shift-T converts a cell to TraditionalForm.

Comment: I now realize that this doesn't answer the question directly. I won't delete it just yet in case there's something helpful in here.